# VBA Scenario Testing in a financial model

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm new to VBA and trying to automate my financial models. I've got this large complex stock valuation model on excel that reads either string bear, bull, or base from a single cell that has a dropdown that has the options of bear, bull, or base. The model will use different inputs depending on if the user chooses the strings bear, bull, or base, and the model will output different values of the stock respectively. In a separate sheet, I'm trying to display, in 3 separate cells, the output of the model (the value of the stock) in the bear, bull, and base case respectively. I could just make 3 models; a bear, bull, and base case, but I thought that might be too bulky, and I just want 1 variable model, instead of 3 fixed models. I'm wondering if VBA allows for a "scenario" type of ability in which it sets a specific cell to a hypothetical value and then takes the value of another cell, without actually modifying my model.

Comment: Where is your code? Sample data? Expected output?

Comment: Create a flowchart of this process with its decision trees, from the point at which the application will accept a value, then maybe it tests for upper and lower bounds (or it can ask for them as a follow-up input), then it goes through a decision tree for such and such ranges and outputs the three values you want with a reference to the next sheet. Sketch it out, do some pseudocode at least, and update your post here.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want -- but it is still unclear. Perhaps provide an example?

One way I'd do it would be to have a fourth dynamic model. This extra model is based on the hypothetical scenarios (e.g. another column for Bear/Bull/Base for each stock -- we can call this extra column BBB2, and the original one with drop down menus for the user BBB1). The fourth model is based only on data from BBB2.

By default when the sheet is opened, BBB2 = BBB1. When a user changes BBB1, BBB2 gets updated. Then, I'd add a function to change everything in BBB2 to bull or base or bear. From there you could manually change a few stocks and see the results in the fourth model.

Comment: Yeah that's the thing. I'm trying to do it purely through excel functions or VBA, without actually making a new sheet.  People have been asking for code but to be honest, I'm not even sure how to start, cause as far as my knowledge goes no amount of if statements can really explain this.

Comment: So let's say I have sheets 1 and 2, on sheet 1 I have a model (which we can simplify to be x+10 = y, where x is the input and y is the output). x can be a bull, bear, or a base, which let's say are 3,1, and 2 respectively. therefore the outputs y will be 13, 11, and 12 based on which of the 3 cases I choose. on sheet 2, im trying to display the variable outputs 13, 11, and 12. note that the actual value for bear, bull, and base case can be changed to any number the user wants, so I couldn't just go bull=base+1.

Comment: I don't think you need vba code to do what you are describing. But if you make a little example of what you are looking for as a final result it may be easier to answer. Basically you want the three outputs to show bull/bear/base outcomes for a single given stock given the current status of the other stocks?